# Почему не работает проверка формы регистрации php

Tags: php, jquery

Не работает проверка полей регистрации

```
 <?php
     include("include/db_connect.php"); 
     include("functions/functions.php"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#form_reg").validate({

            rules: {

                "reg_login": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    remote: {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "/reg/check_login.php"
                    }
                },

                "reg_pass": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 15
                },
                "reg_surname": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15
                },
                "reg_name": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15
                },
                "reg_patronymic": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15
                },
                "reg_email": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true

                },
                "reg_phone": {
                    required: true
                },
                "reg_address": {
                    required: true
                },
                "reg_captcha": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    remote: {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "/reg/check_captcha.php"
                    }
                }
            },

            messages: {

                "reg_login": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    remote: "Login занят"

                },

                "reg_pass": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
                },

                "reg_surname": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
                },

                "reg_name": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
                },
                "reg_patronymic": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
                },


                "reg_email": {
                    required: "Укажи",
                    email: "Некорректный email"

                },
                "reg_phone": {
                    required: "Укажи"


                },
                "reg_address": {
                    required: "Укажи"


                },
                "reg_captcha": {
                    required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                    remote: "Не верно!"

                }

            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == 'true') {
                            $("#block-form-reg").fadeOut(300, function() {
                                $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы            успешно зарегистрировались");
                                $("#form_submit").hide();
                            });
                        } else {
                            $("#reg_message").assClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="block-body">
      <?php
        include("include/block-header.php");  
      ?>
            <div id="block-cont">
                <h2 class="h2-title">Регистрация</h2>
                <form method="post" id="form_reg" action="/reg/handler_reg.php"></form>
                <p id="reg_message"></p>
                <div id="block-form-reg">
                    <ul id="form-reg">
                        <li>
                            <label>Логин</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_login" id="reg_login" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Пароль</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Фамилия</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_surname" id="reg_surname" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Имя</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_name" id="reg_name" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Отчество</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_patronymic" id="reg_patronymic" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <span class="star">*</span>
                            <input type="text" name="reg_email" id="reg_email" />
                            <li>
                                <label>Телефон</label>
                                <span class="star">*</span>
                                <input type="text" name="reg_phone" id="reg_phone" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Адресс</label>
                                <span class="star">*</span>
                                <input type="text" name="reg_address" id="reg_address" />
                            </li>
                            <p align="right">
                                <input type="submit" name="reg_submit" id="form_submit" value="Регистраиця" />
                            </p>
                            <li>
                                <div id="block-captcha">
                                    <img src="/reg/reg_captcha" />
                                    <input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha" />
                                    <p id="reloadcaptcha">Обновить</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
              include("include/block-footer.php");
            ?>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shop-script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас лишний тег закрытия формы:

```
<form method="post" id="form_reg" action="/reg/handler_reg.php"></form>
```

В результате форма пустая. Удалите `</form>`.

Comment: Удалил лишнею </form>, но все так же не показывает проверку