# Не обновляется captcha

Tags: javascript, captcha

Капча работает, но при нажатие обновить она не обновляется, лишь при перезагрузки страницы 
 
Вот блок с капчей

```
<div id="block-captcha"> 
<img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php" /> 
<input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha" /> 
<p id="reloadcaptcha">Обновить</p> 
</div>
```

Файл shop-script.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#select-sort").click(function(){
$("#sorting-list").slideToggle(200);
});
$('#block-category > ul > li > a').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#block-category >ul > li > ul').slideUp(400);
  $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  $('#block-category > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $.cookie('select_cat', $(this).attr('id'));
 }else
 {
$('#block-category > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
$('#block-category > ul > li > ul').slideUp(400);
$.cookie('select_cat', '');

}
});
if ($.cookie('select_cat') != '')
{
$('#block-category >ul > li > #'+$.cookie('select_cat')).assClass('active').next().show();
}

$('#reloadcaptcha').click(function(){
 $('#block-captcha > img').attr("src","/reg/reg_captcha.php?r="+ Math.random());
});

});
```

Файл reg_captcha

```
    <?php
session_start();
$width = 100;                  // ширина
 $height = 50;                  // высота
$font_size = 17.5;              // размер шрифта
$let_amount = 4;               // количество символов капчи
$fon_let_amount = 30;          // количество символов в фоне
$path_fonts = 'fonts/';        // путь до шрифта
 // массив - из каких символов будет состоять капча
 $letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','2','3','4','5','6','7','9');
 // массив цветов
 $colors = array('10','30','50','70','90','110','130','150','170','190','210');
 // создаем изображение
 $src = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
 // создаем фон
 $fon = imagecolorallocate($src,255,255,255);
 // заполняем этим фоном изображение
 imagefill($src,0,0,$fon);
 // массив шрифтов
 $fonts = array();
 // открываем директорию с шрифтами
 $dir=opendir($path_fonts);
 // считываем ширфты
 while($fontName = readdir($dir)) {
 // если это не текущий каталог и не дочерний
 if($fontName != "." && $fontName != "..") {
     // добавляем шрифт к массиву
     $fonts[] = $fontName;
 }
 }
 // закрываем директорию
 closedir($dir);
  // проходим в цикле от 0 - 30
 for($i=0;$i<$fon_let_amount;$i++) {
 // получаем случайный цвет символов
 $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($src,rand(0,255),rand(0,255),rand(0,255),100);
 // случайным образом выбираем шрифт
 $font = $path_fonts.$fonts[rand(0,sizeof($fonts)-1)];
 // случайным образом выбираем символ из массива
 $letter = $letters[rand(0,sizeof($letters)-1)];
 // случайным образом выбираем размер от 17.5 - 2 до 17.5 + 2
 $size = rand($font_size-2,$font_size+2);
 // рисуем символы
 imagettftext($src,$size,rand(0,45),rand($width*0.1,$width-$width*0.1),rand($height*0.2,$height),$color,$font,$letter);
 }
  // проходим в цикле от 0 - 4
 for($i=0;$i<$let_amount;$i++) {
 // получаем случайный цвет
 $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($src,$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],$colors[rand(0,sizeof($colors)-1)],rand(20,40));
 // получаем случайный шрифт
 $font = $path_fonts.$fonts[rand(0,sizeof($fonts)-1)];
 // получаем случайный символ
 $letter = $letters[rand(0,sizeof($letters)-1)];
 // получаем случайный размер
 $size = rand($font_size*2.1-2,$font_size*2.1+2);
 // расположение символа по оси х
 $x = ($i+1)*$font_size + rand(4,7);
 // расположение символа по оси y
 $y = (($height*2)/3) + rand(0,5);
 // добавляем к массиву символ
 $cod[] = $letter;
 // рисуем символ
 imagettftext($src,$size,rand(0,15),$x,$y,$color,$font,$letter);
  }
 // сохраняем в сессии код из 4-х символов
 $_SESSION['img_captcha'] = implode('',$cod);
// отправляем заголовок, что будет изображение gif
header ("Content-type: image/gif");
 // создаем изображение gif
 imagegif($src);
 ?>
```

Файл reg.php

```
    <?php
 include("include/db_connect.php"); 
 include("functions/functions.php"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>Регистрация</title>


</head>

 <body>
<div id="block-body">
  <?php
    include("include/block-header.php");  
  ?>
        <div id="block-cont">
 <form method="post" id="form_reg" action="/reg/handler_reg.php">
<p id="reg_message"></p>
<div id="block-form-reg">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputName">Логин</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="reg_login" id="reg_login" placeholder="Введите Логин" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputPass">Пароль</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass" placeholder="Введите Пароль" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="reg_email" id="reg_email" placeholder="Введите Email" />
</div>
 <div id="block-captcha"> 
 <img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php?1232123" /> 
 <input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha" /> 
  <p id="reloadcaptcha">Обновить</p> 
 </div>
 <p align="right">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-system" name="reg_submit"  id="reg_submit" value="Регистраиця" />
  </div>
 </form>
  </div>
        <?php
          include("include/block-footer.php");
        ?>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shop-script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $("#form_reg").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // прерываем отправку формы
    var data = $('#form_reg').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/reg/handler_reg.php",
        data:data,
        error:function(){
             $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#reg_message").html('Загрузка...');
        },
        success: function(html){
            $("#block-form-reg").fadeOut(300);
          $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_good").fadeIn(400).html(html);
        }

    });

    return false;
  });

</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: скорее всего браузер кеширует картинку и не загружает её по новой, <img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php" />   попробуйте добавить например timestamp в конце урла  <img src="/reg/reg_captcha.php?1232132" />

Comment: Это не помогло((

Comment: что браузер выводит в консоли?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at shop-script.js:1

Comment: jquery не подключена или подключена не правильно. покажи как ты подключаешь скрипты на странице.

Comment: добавил файл reg.php

Answer (score 0):

Важна правильная последовательность подключения библиотек:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/shop-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: скорее всего, это ответ и на предыдущие твои вопросы про ошибку и проверку форм.

Comment: все равно почему то не обновляет, и в консоле жалуется в shop-script на $.cookie

Comment: оооо, спасибо большое, я короче в shop-scripte удалил куки и он теперь обновляет, ураа))

Comment: ну так нужно подключить библиотеку! у тебя эта библиотека подключается в вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639724/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-php

Comment: Я куки подключал для каталога чтобы при обновление страницы он оставался открыт, но он не работал, но у меня же подключена это библиотека?

Comment: А по поводу того вопроса, я передал там полностью проверку формы

Comment: 1) Я добавил подключение библиотеки в ответ. 2) Библиотека должна подключаться во всех местах где она используется. 3) Сейчас тебе будет проще вынести подключение сторонних библиотек в отдельный файл и инклюдить этот файл в шаблоны твоих страниц. 4) Реализовывать запоминание позиции на которой раскрыт каталог лучше через LocalStorage.